# Fetch file name from another path unix

Tags: unix

How can i grep file name (which is in another path).

Example:

My file is in a directory

`/export/home/test` -> under this directory i do have a file called file_test

I want to grep for a file name file_test  from another path `/export/home`, how could this be done?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me.  If you're asking how to specify a file in a different directory, you can use its complete path:  `grep foo /export/home/file_test`

Comment: I want to grep like ls -lrt | grep filename... In both different folders as i mentione above

Comment: If you're looking for the file in a directory tree, you can use find: `find /export/home -name file_test`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean sym-links?

You can register one like this:

`ln -s /export/home/test /export/home`

Generic way:

`ln -s <destination> <link-name>`

Comment: Hi, no sym-links wont help here, because i want to grep for the no of files count both in /export/home/test and /export/home.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ls /export/home/file_test` for that.

[man ls](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ls)